# Jupyterhub - iframe in canvas LMS

Tags: iframe, jupyterhub, canvas-lms

I have two different servers with one Canvas LMS installed and one JupyterHub.

I include as an external app with LTI JupyterHub in Canvas and setting the configuration:

```
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
'headers': {
    'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' https://xxxxxxx.yyy"
}}
```

he problem is that when I click on the "start my server" button (image 1), the iframe is blocked because jupyterhub does not consider it safe.

How do I set the setting "Content-Security-Policy" for the docker and for each jupyterhub user?

I read that there is a jupyter_notebook_config.py file, I tried to set it up but it doesn't seem to work ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
Add to your jupyterhub_config.py:

```
c.Spawner.args = ['--NotebookApp.tornado_settings={"headers":{"Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors * self https://yourwebsitehere.com"}}', '--NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True']

c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = { 'headers': { 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors * self https://yourwebsitehere.com"} }
```